# cygwin seems to be swallowing my carriage returns

Tags: perl, cygwin, carriage-return, line-endings

I have a perl script that grabs some files from a remote server and I'd like to be able to represent progress. The way I'm trying to do it is like this:

```
    print "\tDownloading comp.reg.binary.sdiff.log...\n";
    if(does_file_exist('comp.reg.binary.sdiff.log', @ret)){
        $sftp->get("t-gds/log/comp.reg.binary.sdiff.log", $saveDir, sub {
            my($sftp, $data, $offset, $size) = @_;
            print "\tRead $offset of $size bytes\r";
        });
        print "\n\tDownloaded.\n";
    }else{
        print "\tFile not found on server...skipping.\n";
    }
```

However, cygwin seems to swallow carriage returns and doesn't print anything until the last print statement. I doubt it because the script is running too fast, because when I change \r to \n, I can see them print out slowly.

Does anyone have any idea why it's not working the way it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to set `$|` to 1 first?  Sounds like not.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is probably line-buffered.  Try adding `$| = 1;` to the top of your script.  If that works, there are ways to exercise more find-grained control.

Answer (score 0):

Which terminal are you using? If it's not a cygwin-provided pty (such as the rxvt that ships with cygwin) but instead a Windows console, it is possible that perl cannot detect that it's writing to a terminal, and therefore defaults to buffering the output internally until it can write a good-sized chunk out.

Use `$| = 1;` to suppress this buffering explicitly.